# cat: /proc/net/tcp probe: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I need the data of tcpprobe, but when i run the following code,it shows no such file or directory

```
sudo modprobe tcp_probe
cat /proc/net/tcpprobe
cat: /proc/net/tcpprobe: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Is the module loaded? Check `lsmod | grep tcp_probe`

Comment: tcp_probe used by -1. when i run `rmmod tcp_probe`,it will become used by -1.